# What is the proper way to reference Embedded Resources in .net xmldoc comments?

Tags: .net, embedded-resource, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I have a C# project that uses [xml comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx). I make chm files from them with [Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) via the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB). One of the member functions in this project makes use of an [embedded resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292). I want to reference it in the help file. It seems that sandcastle does not support this, but the xml documentation files it parses does. I say this because of the following example

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays the resource text.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The file is loaded from the <see cref="Resources.TextFile.txt"/>.</remarks>
private static void ShowResource()
{
    // Getting text from embedded resource
}
```

If I compile that code and compile a chm from the resulting xml documentation I get the following in the build log:

```
  Warn: CachedResolveReferenceLinksComponent: Unknown reference link target '!:Resources.HelpTextFile.txt'.
```

And the remarks section is:

```
The help file is loaded from the [!:Resources.TextFile.txt].
```

If I do as [Agent Smith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/) for [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) suggests and change the *<see/>* element to `<see cref="Resources.TextFile"/>` the build log says:

```
Warn: CachedResolveReferenceLinksComponent: Unknown reference link target 'P:ProjectName.Properties.Resources.TextFile'.
```

And the Remarks section of the chm changes to:

```
The help file is loaded from the HelpTextFile().
```

So my question is a two part one:

1. Is my use of the *<see/>* element for referencing a resource correct?
2. Is there a way to get sandcastle to reference an embedded resource in the chm files it generates?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an HTML anchor tag to achieve the same result.  It's like referencing image files using an <img> tag in the XML comments.

```
/// The resources are loaded from
/// <a href="../Resources.TextFile.txt">Resources.TextFile.txt</a>.
```

Include the resource file as a content item in the project.  The example above assumes it's in the root folder.  HTML files are always in the ./html folder so it needs to go up one level.  If you put the file in a subfolder off of the root folder, add its name to the href target: "../FolderName/Resources.TextFile.txt".

If you've applied the Sandcastle Styles patch, you can use an href attribute instead of a cref attribute on the <see> tag.  The file location info would be the same.

```
/// The resources are loaded from
/// <see href="../Resources.TextFile.txt" />.
```

Eric